# how to know when a child window closed in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to delete localstorage of child window when it is closed,

```
var child = window.open('http://google.com','','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');

 $interval(function () {
           checkChild();
        }, 1000);


function checkChild() {
    if (child.closed) {
        alert("Child window closed");   
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

by using this , i need to constantly check after an interval ,is there any straight forward to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var promise, child = window.open('http://google.com', '', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');

function checkChild() {
    if (child && child.closed) {
        alert("Child window closed");
        $interval.cancel(timer);
    }
}

promise = $interval(checkChild, 1000);
```

But be sure that the above solution won't work if you open a different domain using `window.open` due to security issues.